# Makefile permutation

Tags: makefile, permutation, cartesian-product

Bash can produce permutations ([cartesian product](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)):

```
$ echo {1,2}{a,b}
1a 1b 2a 2b
```

I would like to do something similar with a makefile. Here is an example
makefile:

```
all: 1a 1b 2a 2b
```

I would like something like this if possible:

```
NOV = 1 2
OSC = a b
all: $(NOV)$(OSC)
```

However when I use an example like that it just creates "1 2a b" instead of
combining them. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

No need for any complex loops or borrowing from shell.  It is much simpler than that.

```
$(foreach p, $(NOV), $(addprefix $p, $(OSC)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SHELL := /bin/bash

NOV := 1,2
OSC := a,b

NOVW := 1 2
OSCW := a b

EXP := $(shell printf "%s " {$(NOV)}{$(OSC)})
EXPW := $(foreach X,$(NOVW),$(foreach Y,$(OSCW),$(X)$(Y)))

.PHONY: all a b $(EXP) $(EXPW)

all: a b

a: $(EXP)
    @echo target a
    @printf "my first prerequisite is %s\n" "$<"
    @printf "all my prerequisites are %s\n" "$^"

b: $(EXPW)
    @echo target b
    @printf "my first prerequisite is %s\n" "$<"
    @printf "all my prerequisites are %s\n" "$^"
```

Output:

```
$ make
target a
my first prerequisite is 1a
all my prerequisites are 1a 1b 2a 2b
target b
my first prerequisite is 1a
all my prerequisites are 1a 1b 2a 2b
```

Note: the `SHELL` is needed because brace expansion isn't a POSIX feature. The shell used by GNU Make is `/bin/sh` by default. When Bash is run as `/bin/sh`, it doesn't support brace expansion.

Comment: Make doesn't work without the shell. Every recipe line in a Makefile is shell syntax, for which a separate shell process is launched, so that you can't do a `cd` in one line and have it be in that directory in the next line. So basically, that is moot.  The concrete aspect of this that is not "clean" is that a comma-separated data representation is used which doesn't play nicely as a Make word list.

Comment: However, the final `EXP` variable does, at least, for what it's worth. I put the foreach approaches into the same Makefile. Side by side comparison. :)